# ASP.NET Botão só executa o método quando clicado várias vezes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Olá, estou enfrentando um problema chato, pois tenho uma função numa página para cancelar a pesagem. Pesagem por que esta página é uma aplicação que funciona internamente se comunicando com uma balança pela rede, coletando o que está sendo pesado ou não.

Quando clico no botão que deveria fechar o grid no qual está localizado, mantendo apenas um grid primário para seleção do produto a ser pesado, ele não aciona a não ser que eu clique muitas vezes.

Este é a parte do código onde está localizado um timer que executa em ***50 milissegundos*** pegando o valor com precisão:

```
<div id="divBalance" runat="server" class="floating-box-inside" style="width: auto;">
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="updPanScrMan" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:Timer ID="OIVTimer" runat="server" Interval="50" OnTick="OIVTimer_Tick" Enabled="false"></asp:Timer>

                    <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="updProgress">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <div class="loader" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlBalance" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OIVTimer" EventName="Tick" />
                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnConfirmarPesagemOIV" />
                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCancelarPesagemOIV" />
                        </Triggers>

                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblupBalance" Style="text-align: center;">

                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlupBalance" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlupBalance_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="txt_cssclass" Width="200px" Height="30px" Style="margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;">
                                            <asp:ListItem> </asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblScaleAmount" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LAnguageStrings, lblScaleAmount %>" CssClass="lbl_cssclass" Style="text-align: center; font-size: larger; margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;" Width="200px" Height="30px"></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlblScaleAmount" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="txt_cssclass" Style="text-align: center; font-size: x-large; margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;" Width="200px" Height="40px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:Table>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server">

                                <asp:Table runat="server">

                                    <asp:TableRow>
                                        <asp:TableCell>
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirmarPesagemOIV" Text="<%$ Resources:LanguageStrings, btnConfirm %>" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Style="width: 200px; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;" OnClick="btnConfirmarPesagemOIV_Click" />
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableRow>
                                        <asp:TableCell>
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancelarPesagemOIV" Text="<%$ Resources:LanguageStrings, btnCancel %>" CssClass="btn btn-default" Style="width: 200px; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;" OnClick="btnCancelarPesagemOIV_Click" />
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                </asp:Table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
```

Esse é o código executado pelo botão que deveria parar o timer, fechar a conexão e fechar o grid da tela:

```
        protected void btnCancelarPesagemOIV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divAmountsOneIngre.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");
        divBalance.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");

        OIVTimer.Enabled = false;
        Session["ScaleConn"] = null;

        txtlblScaleAmount.Enabled = false;
        txtlblScaleAmount.Text = "";
        txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass";
        SSCC_barcodeReader.Enabled = false;
        SSCC_barcodeReader.Text = "";

        txtlblMtrCod.Text = "";
        txtlblMtrNam.Text = "";
        txtlblLotID.Text = "";
        txtlblLotIDQtd.Text = "";
        txtlblExpDat.Text = "";

        txtlblMax.Text = "";
        txtlblTar.Text = "";
        txtlblMin.Text = "";
        txtlblAct.Text = "";
        txtlblRequired.Text = "";
    }
```

Eu já procurei milhares de soluções e ainda não encontrei nenhuma solução para isso ou outra forma que eu possa realizar isso.

Lembrando: Ao clicar no botão que deveria fechar o grid em apenas um clique, mesmo que com algum delay, ele não o faz. A não ser que eu clique várias vezes no botão.

Este é o código que uso dentro do Timer_Tick():

```
        protected void OIVTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var AmRepo = Session["Material"] as Conaprole_DosimetrySystem.Class.Material;
        var ScaleObj = Session["ScaleConn"] as Conaprole_DosimetrySystem.Class.Scale;

        if (ScaleObj == null)
        {
            OIVTimer.Enabled = false;
            Session.Remove("ScaleConn");

            divAmountsOneIngre.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");
            divBalance.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");

            txtlblScaleAmount.Enabled = false;
            txtlblScaleAmount.Text = "";
            txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass";
            SSCC_barcodeReader.Enabled = true;
            SSCC_barcodeReader.Text = "";

            btnAddToTotal.Enabled = false;
            btnAddToTotal.Visible = false;
            btnScaleOn.Enabled = false;
            btnScaleOn.Visible = false;
            btnFinalize.Enabled = false;
            btnFinalize.Visible = false;
            btnManualConfirm.Enabled = false;
            btnManualConfirm.Visible = false;

            btnCancel.Enabled = false;
            btnCancel.Visible = false;
            btnConfirm.Enabled = false;
            btnConfirm.Visible = false;

            txtlblMtrCod.Text = "";
            txtlblMtrNam.Text = "";
            txtlblLotID.Text = "";
            txtlblLotIDQtd.Text = "";
            txtlblExpDat.Text = "";

            txtlblMax.Text = "";
            txtlblTar.Text = "";
            txtlblMin.Text = "";
            txtlblAct.Text = "";
            txtlblRequired.Text = "";

            btnHide();
        }
        else
        {

            float Max = AmRepo.MaxAmount - AmRepo.ActualAmount;
            float Min = AmRepo.MinAmount - AmRepo.ActualAmount;

            int returnCode = ScaleObj.commandLv0_SI();

            if (returnCode == 0)
            {
                double peso = ScaleObj.weight;

                txtlblScaleAmount.Text = String.Format("{0:F3}", peso);

                if (peso <= 0f)
                {
                    btnConfirmarPesagemOIV.Enabled = false;
                    txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass_scale_red";
                }
                else if (Min <= AmRepo.ContainerTotalAmount)
                {
                    if (peso >= Min || peso <= Max)
                    {
                        if (peso < Min && peso >= 0f)
                        {
                            btnConfirmarPesagemOIV.Enabled = true;
                            txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass_scale_red";
                        }
                        else if (peso > Max && peso >= 0f)
                        {
                            btnConfirmarPesagemOIV.Enabled = false;
                            txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass_scale_red";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            btnConfirmarPesagemOIV.Enabled = true;
                            txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass_scale_green";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btnConfirmarPesagemOIV.Enabled = false;
                        txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass_scale_red";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    btnConfirmarPesagemOIV.Enabled = true;
                    txtlblScaleAmount.CssClass = "txt_cssclass_scale_red";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (returnCode)
                {
                    case -1:
                        txtlblScaleAmount.Text = Resources.LanguageStrings.lblScaleOverload;
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        txtlblScaleAmount.Text = Resources.LanguageStrings.lblScaleUnderload;
                        break;
                    case -3:
                        txtlblScaleAmount.Text = Resources.LanguageStrings.lblScaleBusy;
                        break;
                    case -4:
                        txtlblScaleAmount.Text = Resources.LanguageStrings.lblCantWrite;
                        break;
                    case -5:
                        txtlblScaleAmount.Text = Resources.LanguageStrings.lblCantRead;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Eu sei que parece ser até repetitivo algumas coisas dentro dele, mas algumas foram necessárias outras foram por desespero.
E também esse código foi feito por mim e por mais um colega, enquanto eu estive de férias. Estava funcionando, mas na implementação, encontrei alguns erros. Um dos é esse que vos digo e preciso resolver.

Comment: Porque você precisa de um timer? Talvez a operação executada por ele demore mais que 50ms e isso pode estar enfileirando várias vezes os comandos (suposição, não olhei o código com atenção). Você experimentou aumentar esse intervalo? Tipo pra algo entre 1~5s, é ncessária a dependência dessa latência tão baixa em uma aplicação web?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu preciso sim dessa taxa de atualização tão rápida, pois se trata de uma balança super precisa.

Comment: E você tem certeza de que uma aplicação web baseada em request e response seja a melhor forma de entregar todo esse potencial de broadcast?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Para o cenário que desenvolvi toda essa aplicação é necessária. Antes foi pensado numa aplicação windows, porém os requisitos foram para uma aplicação web. O que me deixa encabulado é que uso esse sistema de timer para comunicação com a balança em duas telas distintas, mas que executa o mesmo código. E na outra eu não enfrento esse problema.